# CLLocationManager doesn't ask me when deployed

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

So I am building an iPhone app and when on the simulator it asks me for permission but when I debug on the device I don't get asked?

Is this something I am overlooking? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone asks sharing permission only one time per app, at the first time.

Comment: Yes, but I deleted the test app and it still doesn't ask.  Should I or can delete the keys from the phone before the app is delete?